# Lookup or invoke block by block description in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

Am new to Drupal , so please excuse if am missing anything obvious.
Can we programmatically lookup a block using the description instead of id ?

Currently am using :

```
module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 17);
```

I wish to use something like

```
module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 'myBlockName');
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "View" Operation of block hook, does a lookup in the database based on "bid"

```
"SELECT body, format FROM {boxes} WHERE bid = {$delta}"
```

So you will not be able to call a block by its name unless you override the hook. ie create your own

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I eventually ended us doing the below. This allows you to avoid hardcoding the block id

```
$result = db_query("Select bid from boxes where info ='your_block_name'");
$row = db_fetch_object($result);
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', $row->bid);
```